# Search through VBA code files in other Access Databases

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I read through a pretty thorough response in the link [How to search through VBA code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118061/how-to-search-through-vba-code-files) and it works just fine for the current project. However, I'm just feeling slow in opening up other projects and looking through their code.

The response mentioned using OpenDatabase but I'm not seeing examples about the association between the database and the Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject. I've not been lazy about this, but 4 days of searching the web has exhausted my options.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

My apologies. Found other way to make this work.

```
Public Sub FindWordInOtherModules(ByVal pSearchWord As String, sApplicationFilePath As String)
Dim objComponent As VBComponent
    ' VBComponent requires reference to Microsoft Visual Basic
    ' for Applications Extensibility; use late binding instead:
Dim lStartLine As Long
Dim lEndLine As Long
Dim lStartColumn As Long
Dim lEndColumn As Long
Dim accApp As Access.Application

Set accApp = New Access.Application

With accApp
    .Visible = True
    .OpenCurrentDatabase (sApplicationFilePath)
    .UserControl = True
    'MsgBox .VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents.Count
    'MsgBox .CurrentDb.Name

    For Each objComponent In .VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
        If objComponent.CodeModule.Find(pSearchWord, lStartLine, lStartColumn, lEndLine, lEndColumn, _
        FindWholeWord, MatchCase, PatternSearch) = True Then
           MsgBox "Found text " & StringToFind & vbCrLf _
               & "Start line: " & lStartLine & vbCrLf _
               & "Line text:  " & objComponent.CodeModule.Lines(lStartLine, lEndLine - lStartLine + 1), vbOKOnly, objComponent.CodeModule.Name
    End If
Next objComponent
End With

accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
Set accApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably add accApp.Quit:

```
accApp.CloseCurrentDatabase
accApp.Quit
Set accApp = Nothing
```

before Set accApp = Nothing to speed up closing the application and close it during execution of this code (Public Sub FindWordInOtherModules), on the line accApp.Quit, not later. On my computer mouse is still inactive several seconds after execution such kind of Sub if accApp.Quit is not added.

But there is no need to open another database, because the current database can be only "linked' to it by creating temporary reference:

```
Private Sub FindWordInOtherModules2()

Dim objComponent As VBComponent
...
...
Dim lEndColumn As Long

Dim ref As Reference
Dim RefName As String

Const FileName = "C:\Users\....mdb"

With Application 'instead of accApp

    .References.AddFromFile FileName
    '.References.Count because the new one is supposed be the last one (?)
    RefName = .References(.References.Count).Name 

    Dim VBProj As VBProject

    For Each VBProj In .VBE.VBProjects
        If VBProj.FileName <> .CurrentDb.Name Then Exit For
    Next

    For Each objComponent In VBProj.VBComponents
        'Debug.Print objComponent.Name
        ...
        ...
    Next

    Set objComponent = Nothing '?
    Set VBProj = Nothing '?

    Set ref = .References(RefName)
    .References.Remove ref
    Set ref = Nothing '??

End With

End Sub
```

This seems be faster then opening another database file, but VBA can't be updated.
`References.Remove ref` removes reference, but VBA folders are still visible in the left panel and all the code works, what is a little disturbing ...

`Application.VBE.VBProjects.Remove VBProj` doesn't work. It may have something to do with "Trust access to the VBA project object model" option in Trust Center - Macro Settings, which is not available in Access.
But the project is not visible after closing and opening the database.