# How to search through VBA code and get all variables and constants?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA It would be helpful to have a summary of all variable and constants names and type in every procedure in my project written into a sheet (not by `Local debug`).

I have found part of a possible solution here [How to search through VBA code files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10118061/how-to-search-through-vba-code-files).

Is there an easier way to do this without writing string edit code?

I want to be sure it is not an overkill to use this partial solution before writing the code that does this.

Comment: What do you mean by *"without writing string edit code"*? Actually the link shows the only way to access VBA code using VBA itself.

Comment: Ok, It is just a little strange that I could not find someone who implemented something like this.

Comment: Actually I see no reason why someone would do what you try to accomplish. Why would you be interested in such a list. If you call a procedure or function you are only interested in the exposed parameters (well you get those by IntelliSense anyway). Procedure scope local variables? I don't care their names I can't deal with them from outside anyway. If your procedures are that big that you cannot keep track of your local variable names and need a list, you're doing it wrong: Splitting your procedures into smaller ones would be a very good idea then. • I see not how this could be helpful.